# How to create two child subsites one under the other by using web template?

Tags: web-template, provisioning

I have this senario where I have to create a sub site and beneath that there will be another subsite created at the moment user creates the top subsite.
Ex:

```
Site1 (On siteCollection user will create a sub site, based on the custom web template. once he hits create, subsite 1 and sub,subsite 1A will be created.)
  -> SubSite 1
       ->Sub,Subsite 1A (child of Site1)
```

I am creating a web template for my first sub site, but how do I create the second sub site automatically when the first site is created?

what is the best approach? do I have to build a second web template and create a sub, subsite based on that template? But then how do I call it within the first web template?